# why kubernetes pods error tips not refresh after fix problem

Tags: kubernetes

My pod get red status and show this error:

```
Usage of EmptyDir volume "agent" exceeds the limit "100Mi".
```

after I fix this problem, the error did not disappear.

[image]

how to make the error tips disappear? This is the pod info:

```
dolphin@dolphins-MacBook-Pro ~ % kubectl describe pods soa-task-745d48d955-bd4j8
Name:           soa-task-745d48d955-bd4j8
Namespace:      dabai-fat
Priority:       0
Node:           azshara-k8s03/172.19.150.82
Start Time:     Tue, 17 Aug 2021 15:23:18 +0800
Labels:         k8s-app=soa-task
                pod-template-hash=745d48d955
Annotations:    kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2021-04-20T07:42:03Z
Status:         Running
IP:             172.30.184.3
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/soa-task-745d48d955
Init Containers:
  init-agent:
    Container ID:  docker://25d947147300edba8bc1861d40cea314047674b74f82d7de9013eead41f1f20f
    Image:         registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/skywalking-agent:6.5.0
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/skywalking-agent@sha256:eda5426bc7bc06fc184e740f4783f263f151ae25e55aae37eec8b67e5dbb2fb0
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      set -ex;mkdir -p /skywalking/agent;cp -r /opt/skywalking/agent/* /skywalking/agent;
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 17 Aug 2021 15:23:19 +0800
      Finished:     Tue, 17 Aug 2021 15:23:19 +0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /skywalking/agent from agent (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-xnrwt (ro)
Containers:
  soa-task:
    Container ID:   docker://5406a90606e0a3905fa8fa4827e19db0d8d58609c06c2fd4e756b718df5db3b9
    Image:          registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-task:v1.0.0
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-task@sha256:aece36589aae4fdedcfb82d7e64e451e32ebb1169dccd2485f8fe4bd451944a8
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 17 Aug 2021 15:23:34 +0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Liveness:       http-get http://:11028/actuator/liveness delay=120s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:11028/actuator/health delay=90s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      SKYWALKING_ADDR:  dabai-skywalking-skywalking-oap.apm.svc.cluster.local:11800
      APOLLO_META:      <set to the key 'apollo.meta' of config map 'fat-config'>  Optional: false
      ENV:              <set to the key 'env' of config map 'fat-config'>          Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /opt/skywalking/agent from agent (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-xnrwt (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  agent:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  100Mi
  default-token-xnrwt:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-xnrwt
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 360s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 360s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  13m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned dabai-fat/soa-task-745d48d955-bd4j8 to azshara-k8s03
  Normal  Pulled     13m   kubelet            Container image "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai_fat/skywalking-agent:6.5.0" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    13m   kubelet            Created container init-agent
  Normal  Started    13m   kubelet            Started container init-agent
  Normal  Pulling    13m   kubelet            Pulling image "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-task:v1.0.0"
  Normal  Pulled     13m   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/dabai_app_k8s/dabai-fat/soa-task:v1.0.0"
  Normal  Created    13m   kubelet            Created container soa-task
  Normal  Started    13m   kubelet            Started container soa-task
```

Comment: output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Comment: Please post output of `kubectl describe pods coredns-df554df8-76lrw -n kube-system`